# Get prefetch cache created status

Tags: sitecore-api

Is there any way to understand the status of prefecth cache ? What i want to understand is that if the prefetch is already created or not ?

When i disassemble the sitecore.kernal , I see a property in Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.initialDataPrefetched , but unfortunately this seems to be a private field.

Answer (score 1):

if you access: **hostname/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx** you will see the value of all caches.

Please search for prefetch and you will see if the prefetch cache is created.

[image]

**Database prefetch caches** contain items that Sitecore accesses during and immediately after initialization, and items with children that Sitecore often accesses as a group. Sitecore populates database prefetch caches at application initialization, and maintains those caches over the life of the application. Each database prefetch cache stores data from a different database or data source. Not all data providers implement prefetch caches.

Comment: lobagiu -  thanks for this  I wanted to get this using sitecore API

Comment: what are you trying to do with that cache ?

Comment: This is basically to understand the health of a server from load balancer. I am delaying the status till the prefetch is loaded after every app pool recycle . but next time onwards i dont want to do this again , i should skip the logic of delaying for which would be great if we have anyway to get the status of prefetch is already in place  . This is an expriment we are trying alternate to keepalive / hearbeat .aspx pages we normally use for health check from LB

Comment: why do you check the health of the server using PrefetchCache ?  What is the logic behind ?

Comment: The prefetch cache load time takes considerable time after the app pool recycle happens and with the normal keepalive.aspx and heartbeat.aspx the LB gets the status quickly irrespective of  prefecth loading and start sending the request to the server . want to keep a logic to let the prefetch load before LB gets the response on health check but again this logic is for the very first time hit and then onwards normal way . so does it requires this flag .